# VBA concatenate selected cells filling a condition

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a function in VBA that allows me to concatenate cells and adding a "," in between elements. The other aspect of this function is that I want only to concatenate the cells that are the same fill color and font color as the first in the range selected. (My spreadsheet has a list of labels that are in cells with different colors and font colors).
If found a code online that works marvels w/o the conditions. But when I try to add them, it returns a value error.
Here is my function:

```
Function Concat(rng As Range) As String 
     Dim rngCell As Range
     Dim strResult As String
     Dim bcolor As Long
     Dim fcolor As Long
     bcolor = rng.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex
     fcolor = rng.Cells(1, 1).Font.ColorIndex
     For Each rngCell In rng
         If rngCell.Value <> "" And rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = bcolor And rngCell.Font.ColorIndex = fcolor Then
            strResult = strResult & "," & rngCell.Value
         End If
     Next rngCell
     If rngCell.Value <> "" And rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = rng.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex And rngCell.Font.ColorIndex = rng.Cells(1, 1).Font.ColorIndex Then
         strResult = Mid(strResult, Len(",") + 1)
     End If
     Concat = strResult
End Function
```

I am very new to VBA (I started this afternoon) so the reason I added the bcolor and fcolor was for debugging. Actually I think there is something fundamental i don't understand in VBA because even the following function doesn't return any value:

```
Function Concat(rng As Range) As Long 'Replace "Long" by "String" after debug is over
     Dim rngCell As Range
     Dim strResult As String
     Dim bcolor As Long
     Dim fcolor As Long
     bcolor = rng.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex
     fcolor = rng.Cells(1, 1).Font.ColorIndex
     For Each rngCell In rng
         If rngCell.Value <> "" And rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = bcolor And rngCell.Font.ColorIndex = fcolor Then
            strResult = strResult & "," & rngCell.Value
         End If
     Next rngCell
     If rngCell.Value <> "" And rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = rng.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex And rngCell.Font.ColorIndex = rng.Cells(1, 1).Font.ColorIndex Then
         strResult = Mid(strResult, Len(",") + 1)
     End If
     Concat = bcolor
End Function
```

It really bugs me that this function doesn't return the color of the cell while he following does:

```
Function color1(rng As Range) As Long
    color1 = rng.Cells(1, 1).Font.ColorIndex
End Function
```

I know there is something fundamental I don't understand about VBA coding here. But I can't tell what. If you see what is wrong, I would appreciate a correction and an explanation of what my mistake is.
Thanks!
Xavier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am not sure the last part of the code does what you want it to do. Also, you can't use the `rngCell` outside the `For Each rngCell In rng`.

The inside of the statement only removes the first character of the string. (`Mid()` truncates a string starting at the character at the position passed in parameter, if a second number is to be supplied, it will set the amount of characters the sub-string will contain; `Len()` will return the length of the string supplied).

So the `strResult = Mid(strResult, Len(",") + 1)` pretty much means, store a string of the original string, but starting at character 2 (1 + 1).

Try this!

```
Function Concat(rng As Range) As String
     Dim rngCell As Range
     Dim strResult As String
     Dim bcolor As Long
     Dim fcolor As Long
     bcolor = rng.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex
     fcolor = rng.Cells(1, 1).Font.ColorIndex
     For Each rngCell In rng

         If rngCell.Value <> "" And rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = bcolor And rngCell.Font.ColorIndex = fcolor Then
            If strResult = "" Then
                strResult = rngCell.Value
            Else
                strResult = strResult & ", " & rngCell.Value
            End If
         End If

     Next rngCell
     'this probably doesn't do what you want, so I commented it out.
     'If rngCell.Value <> "" And rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = rng.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex And rngCell.Font.ColorIndex = rng.Cells(1, 1).Font.ColorIndex Then
     '    strResult = Mid(strResult, Len(",") + 1)
     'End If
     Concat = strResult
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try your code right away. The reason the extra if is here is that otherwise, my returned string starts with a ",". I'll be back in a bit after trying out the function.

Comment: Actually after trying, I understand even less. When compiling, the compiler tells me that there is an error because there is a Next without a For (which is clearly not true) since there is only one Next and one For!
Reading your code, I do think it is much more elegant in removing the first ","!

Comment: Actually, the reason for the error what that a End If was missing after your added If. The code works!

Comment: Oh, my.. Maybe I should have tested more dilligently :)

Comment: If you have a minute to explain why adding those supplemental conditions in If broke my code that would be much appreciated :)

Comment: You mean, why your original `If` (the one I commented out) didn't work? It's because you're using the variable `rngCell` which is not defined outside of the `For Each... Next` loop.

Comment: I meant why did the original code I found online worked (the second If is also outside the loop but it still worked)? Or maybe while rearranging I changed the order inadvertently.

Comment: @user3200894 most likely. You got it working now? :D

Comment: The thing is, with the way your `If` is declared, even if it was inside the loop (where the object was declared), it wouldn't work as expected, since it'd remove the first character everytime.

Answer (score 0):

For **Concat()** to return a value, your function must assign a value to the variable within the body of the function.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I changed the name of the function to make it more readable and forgot to change it inside the code. I do use the same name. Thanks for pointing it out! I edited the question.